# RabbitMQ SSL Configuration: DotNet Client

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, client-certificates, x509certificate2

I am trying to connect (dotnet client) to RabbitMQ. I enabled the Peer verification option from the RabbitMQ config file.

```
 _factory = new ConnectionFactory
                {
                    HostName = Endpoint,
                    UserName = Username,
                    Password = Password,
                    Port = 5671,
                    VirtualHost = "/",
                    AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true                       
                };

sslOption = new SslOption
            {
                Version = SslProtocols.Tls12,
                Enabled = true,
                AcceptablePolicyErrors = System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors
                                         | System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch,
                ServerName = "", // ?
                Certs = X509CertCollection
            }
```

Below are my client certification details which I am passing through "X509CertCollection".

CertSubject: CN=myhostname, O=MyOrganizationName, C=US // myhostname is the name of my client host.

So, if I pass "myhostname" value into sslOption.ServerName, it works. If I pass some garbage value, it still works.

As per documentation of RabbitMQ, these two value should be match i.e. certCN value and serverName.  What will be the value of sslOption.ServerName here and why?

Answer (score 0):

My Bad. I found the reason. Posting as it might help someone.
Reason: As I set a policy "System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch".